# Python random function

Tags: python, random, import

I'm having problems with Python's import random function. It seems that `import random` and `from random import random` are importing different things. I am currently using Python 2.7.3

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2012, 23:31:26) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> random()

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    random()
NameError: name 'random' is not defined
>>> random.randint(1,5)

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
random.randint(1,5)
NameError: name 'random' is not defined
>>> import random
>>> random()

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
random()

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
>>> random.randint(1,5)
2
>>> from random import random
>>> random()
0.28242411635200193
>>> random.randint(1,5)

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#7>", line 1, in <module>
random.randint(1,5)
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'randint'
>>>
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`import random` imports the random *module*, which contains a variety of things to do with random number generation. Among these is the random() *function*, which generates random numbers between 0 and 1.

Doing the import this way this requires you to use the syntax `random.random()`.

The random function can also be imported from the module separately:

```
from random import random
```

This allows you to then just call `random()` directly.

Answer (score 21):

The [random module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html) contains a function named `random()`, so you need to be aware of whether you have imported the module into your namespace, or imported functions from the module.

`import random` will import the random module whereas `from random import random` will specifically import the random function from the module.

So you will be able to do one of the following:

```
import random
a = random.random()
b = random.randint(1, 5)
# you can call any function from the random module using random.<function>
```

or...

```
from random import random, randint   # add any other functions you need here
a = random()
b = randint(1, 5)
# those function names from the import statement are added to your namespace
```

Answer (score 9):

The problem is that there are two things called random here: one is the module itself, and one is a function within that module. You can't have two things with the same name in your namespace so you have to pick one or the other.

Answer (score 6):

```
import random
```

includes the module into the namespace under the name 'random'.

```
from random import random
```

includes the function'random' from the namespace 'random' into the global namespace.

So in the first example, you would call random.random, and in the second, you would call random.  Both would access the same function.

Similarly,

```
from random import randint
```

would import randint into the global namespace, so you could simply call randint instead of random.randint.

Answer (score 4):

Well, yes, they import different things.  `import random` imports the `random` module, `from random import random` imports the `random` function from the `random` module.  This is actually a good example of why when designing an API in Python, it's often a good idea to try to avoid naming modules and their members the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

The 'random' module is a package from the python standard library, as well as a function defined in this package.

Using 'import random' imports the package, which you can then use the function from this package: 'random.random()'. You can use any other function from the 'random' package as well.

You can also tell python to specifically import only the random function from the package random: 'from random import random'. Then you can only use the function 'random()', and should not specify the package it comes from. However you cannot use any other function from the random package, because they have not been imported if you use 'from random import random'.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `from random import random`, you must call randint() like so: `randint(1,5)`. If you use `import random`, you call it like so: `random.randint(1,5)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PyDev or other clever IDE, make sure it did not import the module automatically, overriding your import. It can be especially confusing here, when module name is equal to a function name, because the error thrown is not a `NameError`. In my case I added

```
import random
```

and later used it:

```
r = random.radom()
```

but got:

```
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'random'
```

Only after searching I found that PyDev automatically added the line

```
from random import random
```

to the end of my imports, so I was in fact calling attribute `random` of method `random`. Solution is to delete the automatic import or use it and call the `random()` method directly.

Answer (score 0):

You have to import the random *function*, from the random *module* before you can use it use it

```
In [1]: from random import random

In [2]: random()
Out[2]: 0.5607917948041573
```