# Using import random, using random.choice throws AttributeError

Tags: python, random, python-import

So, I'm getting a really weird error.  For some reason python is not importing random as the module, and seems to me to be importing it as a function ([as seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14985798/python-random-function)).  Why is it doing this?  Using `import random` and `random.choice()` works fine in other modules.  Why not here?

update: Turns out I was defining random again in logic.py.  I had forgot I did this since I wasn't using it anymore.  Commented it out and it works fine.

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:\workspace37\RockPaperScissors\irps\driver.py", line 20, in <module>
    print "%r" % dtree.root.get_value(history)
  File "H:\workspace37\RockPaperScissors\irps\datastructures.py", line 69, in get_value
    return self.operation(self.left.get_value(history), self.right.get_value(history))
  File "H:\workspace37\RockPaperScissors\irps\datastructures.py", line 69, in get_value
    return self.operation(self.left.get_value(history), self.right.get_value(history))
  File "H:\workspace37\RockPaperScissors\irps\logic.py", line 53, in either
    return random.choice((a, b))
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'choice'
```

I've tried to include the relevant bits of code.

logic.py:

```
import random 
#from random import choice # works if I change random.choice(...) to just choice(...)

ROCK = 'R'
PAPER = 'P'
SCISSORS = 'S'
RPS_TUPLE = (ROCK, PAPER, SCISSORS)
RPS_SET = set((ROCK, PAPER, SCISSORS))
PLAYER = 0
OPPONENT = 1
PLAYERS = (PLAYER, OPPONENT)

def assert_in_set(a, b):
    assert a in RPS_SET
    assert b in RPS_SET

def neither(a, b):
    assert_in_set(a, b)
    diff = RPS_SET.difference((a, b))
    print "diff = ", diff
    return random.choice(tuple(diff))

def either(a, b):
    assert_in_set(a, b)
    return random.choice((a, b)) #line 53

#EDITED TO INCLUDE THESE LINES FURTHER DOWN
def random(a, b):
    return random.choice(RPS_TUPLE)

ALL_OPERATORS = (neither, either)
```

datastructures.py

```
from collections import deque
from logic import RPS_TUPLE, ALL_OPERATORS, PLAYERS
import random
import sys

class OperationNode(TreeNode):

    def __init__(self, parent, left, right, operation):
        super(OperationNode, self).__init__(parent, left, right)
        self.operation = operation

    def get_value(self, history):
        return self.operation(self.left.get_value(history), self.right.get_value(history)) # line 69


class TerminalNode(TreeNode):

    def __init__(self, parent, player, position):
        super(TerminalNode, self).__init__(parent, None, None)
        self.player = player
        self.position = position

    def get_value(self, history):
        # history is a deque of tuples
        return history[self.position][self.player]
```

Comment: Did you define `random` function in `logic.py` ?

Comment: Have you saved the file correctly before rerunning it? Have you got `from random import random` anywhere?

Comment: Try printing `random.__name__` right before the attribute error.  That  would at least tell you which function it thinks `random` is which might lead you to the actual problem elsewhere...

Comment: @falsetru random was defined later in the logic.py file.  I had forgot I had done that since I wasn't using it anymore.  This was the problem. edit: If you want to post this as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you define random function in logic.py?

That could be a cause of a problem.

```
>>> def random():
...     pass
...
>>> random.choice
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'choice'
```