# How to use kneighbors function on joblib loaded model

Tags: scikit-learn, joblib

I am trying to use joblib to import a trained model and without having to train it again.

I tried this code:

```py
filename = "Nearest_neighbors_model.pkl"

loaded_model = joblib.load(filename)
for x in (loaded_model.kneighbors([df.iloc[random(range(0,df.__len__()))]],n_neighbors= 50,  return_distance=False))[0]:
    print(lookupdata.iloc[x])
```

But I keep getting a

```
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Comment: That's a very long line of code that (presumably) the error is being thrown from; try breaking it up to see where the problem is actually coming from (and always report the full error traceback).

Comment: I would guess you've imported `random` the module, not the function `random` that lives inside that module: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14985798/10495893